# Regex Absolute path matching - Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking to check if the path I'm receiving is an absolute path.

This is my requirements:

- Begins with "/"
- Consists only of English letters, numbers, and the special characters   '_', 
  '.', '-', '~' and '/'.
- Does not contain any occurrences of the string "/../".

I tried several expressions and couldn't find the correct one. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should post what you've tried as well as sample strings to test against (valid and invalid ones): `^(?!.*\/\.{2}\/)\/[\w.~\/-]*$`

Comment: Wouldn't you rather use `getAbsolutePath()` for this? Might be more bulletproof than a simple regex...

Comment: Tim, I'm looking to validate a string received by the client - I'm not sure getAbsolutePath() is what I need in this situation

Comment: Comparing the client string and its `getAbsolutePath()` result should show if the client string is different from its absolute path (and therefore not an absolute path itself), shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/qZHdIF/2)

```
^(?!.*\/\.{2}\/)\/[\w.~\/-]*$
```

#### Usage

**Note**: The first two strings in the array are invalid since they contain `/../`. The third string contains an invalid character `:`.

```js
var a = [
  "/../",
  "/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/../0123456789~-_./",
  "/:",
  "/.",
  "/././",
  "/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/0123456789~-_./"
];
var r = /^(?!.*\/\.{2}\/)\/[\w.~\/-]*$/;

a.forEach(function(s){
  console.log(r.test(s));
});
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the string
- `(?!.*\/\.{2}\/)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match

  - `.*` Any character any number of times
  - `\/` Matches a literal slash `/`
  - `\.{2}` Matches the dot character literally, twice
  - `\/` Matches a literal slash `/`
- `\/` Matches a literal slash `/`
- `[\w.~\/-]*` Match any character in the set (word characters, `.`, `~`, `/`, `-`) any number of times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line